# In yii how to create widget to display textfields

Tags: yii

I am about to build a project in Yii. I want to create a widget in such a way that when user will click button that widget with two text-fields for entering new password and repeat password should get display. Also one button will be provided on widget form in order to submit this new password and store it into database.How can i achieve these?

Comment: What are you asking? How to make a widget? How to make the form? How to save the new user password? All of the above? You need to give us some insight into your project if you want help. What does your user table look like? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a model for your table first, say `User`. In User table you may have several columns, among one of them is used for storing password say `password`.
and in your `User` model, you should define rules like below

```
array('password, repeat_password', 'required', 'on'=>'signup'),
array('password', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'repeat_password','on'=>'signup'),
```

the **repeat_password** is a model variable,that you should declare.

and in form, use something like below

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password'); ?>
<?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password'); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>

<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'repeat_password'); ?>
<?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'repeat_password); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'repeat_password'); ?>
```

I think you are asking about a popup form too, for that check these places

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiDialog

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/72/cjuidialog-and-ajaxsubmitbutton

Comment: Actually,i am creating forget password functionality.After answering correctly answer of security question, i want to display two radio buttons.First having label as-"Want to change password here". Second having label as-"Send password reset link to my email id". So after clicking on first radio button,i want to call widget so that it will provide two textfields for entering new password and repeat password and also one submit button. So in what way i should do this.Please help me sir....

Comment: Sorry I have no time now :(, will update my answer later, you may need `renderPartial` method, above rules etc., will update my answer

Comment: I had created simple widget as -<?php
class Sample extends CWidget {
public function init() {
Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerScript(
'SampleWidget',
"alert('Enter new password');");}}.                                  This code i had created in sample.php file which i had placed in sample folder created in protected->extensions->sample.  By using code as-"<?php $this->widget('ext.sample.Sample'); ?>" i am daisplaying msg. But now i want to add two textfields for entering pasword and repeat password in this widget window. So how to implement this. Please help me.

Comment: also want to ask... can i render any view in widget? suppose i want to render password.php view. So how can i do this?